# Install Dreamfactory on Xampp

Tags: mysql, api, rest, xampp, dreamfactory

I have been trying to install Dreamfactory on Xampp but can't find a single article on how to do so.

**Purpose:** To generate REST API in php with mysql.

**What I have tried:**

Initially I installed windows version of
[Dreamfactory](https://bitnami.com/stack/dreamfactory/installer) from official site. It was installed successfully but it don't allow access to MYSQL database in free version. Paid version is out of my budget, so I tried with Xampp. I downloaded open-source version from
[Github](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dreamfactory). After extracting it, executed `php artisan serve` in xampp command shell as mentioned on [Dreamfactory Wikipedia Installation guide](https://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Installation). This resulted in following error:

```
Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\dreamfactory\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\dreamfactory\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\dreamfactory\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\dreamfactory\public\index.php on line 24
```

As mentioned in Git documentation, they have given installation procedures for Ubuntu and Debian. Further more, they have mentioned about Bitnami official installation software, but non for XAMPP or stuff like that.

**Question:**

Is there any way we can install Dreamfactory on XAMPP? If yes, how so!

Comment: The given error message is in no way related to MySQL - also, searching for a tutorial about how to run a specific software is off-topic on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I'd venture it's going to be fairly difficult task to run [DreamFactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com/) on XAMPP because DreamFactory requires quite a few dependencies which are not installed on XAMPP by default.

Your best bet would be to run the Bitnami for DreamFactory environment, or alternatively use Docker. Both can be downloaded from the DreamFactory website [downloads page](https://www.dreamfactory.com/downloads/). Alternatively, if you'd like to run DreamFactory in a VM, the [OSS download README](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dreamfactory) points to automated installers for Debian and Ubuntu. Additional installers for CentOS and Fedora are found [here](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/df-genie), they work great however we just haven't moved them into the official distribution yet.